# How to complain about an abusive editor?

Tags: publications, journals, ethics, editors

It is well known in my field that a particular good journal has an editor-in-chief that frequently asks authors to cite a particular (largely unrelated) paper whenever he has the chance.

Looking at google scholars citations of this particular paper, you can notice that it has a large amount of citations from this particular journal. Reading the papers you can almost see the struggle of the authors trying to cite an unrelated paper.

This has been going on for years.

What can I do to try to stop this? I frequently avoid submitting to this journal due to this issue.

Comment: "I frequently avoid submitting to this journal due to this issue." That's a solution.  Why do you think this is a "good" journal?

Comment: Prestigious overall, high impact factor, etc...

Comment: If you have proof of this send it to the publisher and cc Thomson Reuters. The journal might lose its impact factor. I'd expect the publisher to react quickly. See http://retractionwatch.com/2017/02/24/editor-steps-journal-investigates-citation-irregularities/

Comment: Seems like a highly dangerous practice if true

Comment: I agree, this is highly dubious. Usually the EIC is simply farming out to an editor, and in turn to reviewers, so for the EIC to add such a requirement would be astonishing. The EIC normally just forwards the recommendation without comment. If true, this should be reported to the publisher.

Comment: In my own area, I have experienced this first hand, both from the EiC and also an area editor who wants me to cite 30+ of his papers before acceptance.

Comment: I had a rather similar experience. I simply withdrew my paper. After all, I think there is no shortage of good journals.

Comment: There should be a paper trail of the editor requesting the citations, cases where people are uncomfortable ("but this is not related to my paper") and the editor dismissing their concerns. This paper trail should reach the owners of the journal or whoever is responsible at some point.

Comment: The editor is one of the reviewer and he has right to ask for citing a particular paper if he thinks it is highly related to the submited paper (the reason might be different but you can never prove it). However, it is very easy to avoir citing the paper if you think it is unrelated, by politly responding in the letter that there is no way to cite the paper. 

PS. it happend to me two times and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to stop, the best way to address the issue is to address it with the editor himself. That's not a guarantee that it will be addressed, it could very well be the case that the editor is aware of how his requests are perceived by the most people in the field, and is choosing to run the journal this way anyways.

You mentioned that you avoid submitting to this journal. If you want to lower the prestige of the journal, you could publicize the unprofessional practices of the editor, and encourage your colleagues to submit to better, more professional journals instead. As [MxNx](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/57054/mxnx) mentioned in the comments, there are many good journals they could submit to instead. If many people in your field stop submitting to this journal, chances are it will fall in prestige and possibly fail eventually, unless the practices change.